# Getting TestRestTemplate to work with https

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Writing JUnit Integrtaion tests for a REST endpoint which sets secure cookies, can't get past the ResourceAccessException error.

Requirement is to do a  https://localhost:8443 request.

Have tried using the customRestTemplate

Getting the folloiwng exception.

**org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/dcs": Connect to localhost:8443 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException**

Below is the code.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DcsServiceTests {

        @Autowired
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

        @Autowired
        private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

        @Test
        public void testGet_ImageResponse() throws Exception {

            //Arrange

            //Act
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, byte[].class);

            //Assert
            //Response Status
            assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
            //Response has cookie
            assertThat(response.getHeaders().containsKey("Set-Cookie")).isTrue();
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void initialize() {

            // Lambda expression not working, TBD - Java version used. 
            //TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

            final TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean isTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
                    new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

            try {
                SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                        .build();

                SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

                CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                        .build();

                requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);           
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured creating Request Factory");
            }

            RestTemplate customTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .requestFactory(requestFactory)
                .rootUri("https://localhost:8443")
                .build();
            this.testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(
                    customTemplate,
                    null, 
                    null,  // Not using basic auth 
                    TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES); // Cookie support 

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling SSL and then using testRestTemplate with exchange method worked. Secured cookies works as well, just that the headers needs to be parsed to validate results in Unit test cases

```
@Bean
public Boolean disableSSLValidation() throws Exception {
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    } }, null);

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}


public void hostNameVerifier() {
    final HostnameVerifier defaultHostnameVerifier = javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier ();
    final HostnameVerifier localhostAcceptedHostnameVerifier = new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier () {
       public boolean verify ( String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession ) {
            if ( hostname.equals ( "localhost" ) ) {
                return true;
            }
             return defaultHostnameVerifier.verify ( hostname, sslSession );
        }
    };
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier ( localhostAcceptedHostnameVerifier );
}

@Test
public void testGet_ImageResponse() throws Exception {

    //Arrange       
    String url = getUrl() +  "/xyz?s_action=test&s_type=i";

    //Act
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, byte[].class);

    //Assert
    //Response Status
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    //Response has cookie
    assertThat(response.getHeaders().containsKey("Set-Cookie")).isTrue();

    //Extract cookie from header
    List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");

    //Construct cookie from RAW Header Response
    Cookie cookie = RawCookieParser.constructCookieFromHeaderResponse(response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie").toString());

    //Cookies name matches 
    //Cookie value cannot be matched because value is being set from external JAR
    assertEquals(cookie.getName(), appConfig.getName());

    //Cookie domain matches 
    assertEquals(cookie.getDomain(), appConfig.getDomain());

}

    public class RawCookieParser {


        /*
         * Construct a cookie object by parsing the HTTP Header response
         */
        public static Cookie constructCookieFromHeaderResponse(String input) throws Exception {

            String rawCookie = input.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            String[] rawCookieParams = rawCookie.split(";");
            String[] rawCookieNameAndValue = rawCookieParams[0].split("=");
            if (rawCookieNameAndValue.length != 2) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid cookie: missing name and value.");
            }
            String cookieName = rawCookieNameAndValue[0].trim();
            String cookieValue = rawCookieNameAndValue[1].trim();
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);

            for (int i = 1; i < rawCookieParams.length; i++) {
                String rawCookieParamNameAndValue[] = rawCookieParams[i].trim().split("=");
                String paramName = rawCookieParamNameAndValue[0].trim();

                if (rawCookieParamNameAndValue.length == 2) {

                    String paramValue = rawCookieParamNameAndValue[1].trim();
                    if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("secure"))  {
                        cookie.setSecure(true);                 
                    } else if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("max-age")) {
                        int maxAge = Integer.parseInt(paramValue);
                        cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge);
                    } else if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("domain")) {
                        cookie.setDomain(paramValue);
                    } else if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("path")) {
                        cookie.setPath(paramValue);
                    } 
                }
            }

           return cookie;
        }

    }
```